# Error on implementing geolocation tracking in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation

I am trying to implement geolocation on my new project. I have installed the below plugins and added them in `app.module.ts`

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation`

I am following [this tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/) but getting error in `home.ts`. Below is my `home.ts` code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BackgroundGeolocation, BackgroundGeolocationConfig, BackgroundGeolocationResponse } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation,public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
    desiredAccuracy: 10,
    stationaryRadius: 20,
    distanceFilter: 30,
    debug: true, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
    stopOnTerminate: false, // enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
};

this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
.subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {

console.log(location);

// IMPORTANT:  You must execute the finish method here to inform the native plugin that you're finished,
// and the background-task may be completed.  You must do this regardless if your HTTP request is successful or not.
// IF YOU DON'T, ios will CRASH YOUR APP for spending too much time in the background.
//this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY

});

// start recording location
this.backgroundGeolocation.start();

// If you wish to turn OFF background-tracking, call the #stop method.
this.backgroundGeolocation.stop();

}
```

Error is on this line: `this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)`. On `this` it's saying;

> [ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

And on config it's saying:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'config'

Comment: Are you calling `this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)` outside the constructor?

Comment: Also that is a code snippet from documentation.. not a tutorial link

Answer (score 0):

As @SurajRao was pointing in his comment, you need to move your code either inside the class constructor or wrap it in a method.

Here is your component with the code placed inside the constructor:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BackgroundGeolocation, BackgroundGeolocationConfig, BackgroundGeolocationResponse } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation,public navCtrl: NavController) {
    const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 30,
      debug: true,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
    };
    this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
    .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
      console.log(location);
    });
    this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
    this.backgroundGeolocation.stop();
  }

}
```

Read more about [JavaScript classes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).